# Find number between two alphabets in an alphanumeric text in a pyspark dataframe column

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have a column in my dataframe with below values

```
A123R221343
A12323Q123213
L122F898
```

There is always 2 alphabets in text, first character and 2nd alphabet could be in 4th,5th,6th or 7th character.

I would like to derive a new column in pyspark with only digits in between them

```
123
12323
122
```

I tried regex `[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]`  & `[\d].*[A-Za-z]` but its getting me the alphabets also which I do not want.  I'm completely new with regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]` will match any character from the first occurrence of `[A-Za-z]` till the last occurrence of `[A-Za-z]`

Using `[\d].*[A-Za-z]` does the same, only starting with a digit and does not make sure that there is a char A-Za-z before it.

---

What you can do is capture only digits in a capture group between 2 matches:

```
[A-Za-z](\d+)[A-Za-z]
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sEOg9Z/1)

Comment: I know that you are referring to `[\d].*[A-Za-z]` from the question and not endorsing the need to put `\d` in a character class (as `[\d]` is the same as `\d`).